# Location for `checkstyle-suppressions.xml`?

Tags: java, heroku, jersey, checkstyle

On `git push heroku master`, I am getting this error:

> Unable to find suppressions file at location: etc/config/checkstyle-suppressions.xml: Could not find resource 'etc/config/checkstyle-suppressions.xml'.

I found a sample `checkstyle-suppressions.xml` file, just to get started, [here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/etc/config/checkstyle-suppressions.xml), and added it to `my_app/target/test-classes/org/glassfish/jersey/etc/config/checkstyle-suppressions.xml` and reran `git push heroku master`, but I got the same build error.

What is the correct location for `checkstyle-suppressions.xml`?

Comment: you can talk about style in meeting with the team and in code reviews, but please don't fail builds because of style; it's frustrating and counter-productive. Eject checkstyle.

Comment: What is the correct way to eject checkstyle?

Answer (score 0):

> Could not find resource 'etc/config/checkstyle-suppressions.xml'

[As defined in the documentation for the filter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_filters.html#SuppressionFilter), this is either a file location or a classpath location in your situation.

If it is a file location, it depends on how you are running Checkstyle. Running by CLI, it is relative to the working directory. Running by maven, it is relative to the POM.

If it is a classpath location, it depends what is added to your classpath. By maven, this would usually be under `src/main/resources`.

> I found a sample checkstyle-suppressions.xml file, just to get started, here
>   my_app/target/test-classes/org/glassfish/jersey/etc/config/checkstyle-suppressions.xml

I would start by duplicating it's configuration location assuming you copied their Maven configuration. So the file should be at `my_app/etc/config/checkstyle-suppressions.xml`.

Comment: I moved the file to `my_app/etc/config/checkstyle-suppressions.xml` but still am getting that error. Is there a way to totally deactivate this filter from inside the project -- e.g. an entry in the pom.xml file? I tried adding this to pom.xml: `   <properties>
        <checkstyle.skip>true</checkstyle.skip>
    </properties>` ... but I'm still getting the error message.

Comment: To deactivate the filter, just remove it from your Checkstyle configuration file, wherever that is located. Adding `checkstyle.skip` will disable the entire maven checkstyle plugin. Adding that property disabled it for me, so if it is not for you, then either Checkstyle is not being run by maven, or you didn't modify/save the correct pom. Without seeing your repository, I can't really say what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Is the `Checkstyle configuration file` separate from pom.xml? Where can I find it? As you can see I am new to Java devops. Thanks in advance for any info.

Comment: Yes it is a separate file that you define in the POM. See https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/pom.xml#L487 and https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/etc/config/checkstyle.xml